# Displaying Unique Temperature Values for the US

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, partition-by

I am looking to do something similar to what I did in R (below) in SQL:

```
clim_data %>%
select(Year, AverageTemperature, State) %>%
group_by(Year,State) %>%
summarize(value = mean(AverageTemperature), .groups = 'drop') -> clim_data3

colnames(clim_data3)[2] <- "region" 
clim_data3$region<-tolower(clim_data3$region)

clim_data3 %>%
filter(Year==1900) -> clim_data1900
clim_data1900<-clim_data1900[,2:3]
```

The output of this code looks like this:

```
region  value
<chr>   <dbl>
alabama 17.059167
alaska  -5.146500
arizona 15.742917
arkansas    15.893417
california  14.51575
```

So far in SQL I have managed to output a single state using the following code:

```
select distinct year, round(avg(AverageTemperature) over (partition by year),2) as avgTemp, Country, State
from dbo.landTemps
where AverageTemperature is not null and 
    Country = 'United States' and 
    state = 'Alabama' and
    year = 1900
```

The output looks like this:

```
year    avgTemp   Country        State
1900    17.06   United States   Alabama
```

However, I am unable to get the unique avgTemp for each state. When I take it to more than one state, I get the same avgTemp for all states in that query. So if I run a query like this:

```
select distinct year, round(avg(AverageTemperature) over (partition by year),2) as avgTemp, Country, State
from dbo.landTemps
where AverageTemperature is not null and 
    Country = 'United States' and 
    state like 'A%' and
    year = 1900
```

I get the average for those states.

```
year    avgTemp   Country        State
1900    15.15   United States   Alaska
1900    15.15   United States   Arizona
1900    15.15   United States   Arkansas
1900    15.15   United States   Alabama
```

I am assuming I need to write a subquery of some sort to iterate through each state and give the avgTemp. I tried to partition over the state as well and it didn't give me what I wanted. My overall goal is to print out each states avgTemp for the given year.

The dataset contains multiple values for each year and state:

```
select year, round(avg(AverageTemperature) over (partition by year),2) as avgTemp, Country, State
from dbo.landTemps
where AverageTemperature is not null and 
    Country = 'United States' and 
    state like 'A%' and
    year = 1900

output: 
year    avgTemp  Country         State
1900    15.15   United States   Alabama
1900    15.15   United States   Alabama
1900    15.15   United States   Alabama
1900    15.15   United States   Alabama
```

With more Alabama entries and the other 'A' states below it, so I think using distinct year is imperative. I am just stuck and expanding the single state out into multiple without then taking the average of all the states in the query. The data set can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/berkeleyearth/climate-change-earth-surface-temperature-data?select=GlobalLandTemperaturesByState.csv

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking for the average temperature for each state, you should add the *State* column to the partition by clause.

Try:

```
select year, round(avg(AverageTemperature) over (partition by year,State),2) as avgTemp, Country, State
from dbo.landTemps
where AverageTemperature is not null and 
    Country = 'United States' and 
    state like 'A%' and
    year = 1900
```

Comment: Thank you SO much. I didn't realize you could partition by multiple things in the same clause but that did it!

Answer (score 1):

You want GROUP BY and and the regular aggregate function AVG(),  `AVG() over (partition by...)` is an analytic function not a regular aggregate.  EG

```
select  Country, State, year, avg(AverageTemperature) as avgTemp
from dbo.landTemps
where AverageTemperature is not null
group by Country, State, year
```

Comment: Thank you! Both yours and Pietro's code output what I was looking for. Seems like I was trying to make it a little too difficult adding a partition by into the code.